# Cannot convert type Int to List

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, if-statement

I am trying to create a function on my restaurant review website that finds out if a restaurant has been reviewed. If the restaurant hasn't been reviewed it returns a variable. However I keep on getting the error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>'` on the line `if (restaurantreview = 0).`

Any help would be grateful.

```
var restaurantreview = objCtx.Reviews.Where(r => r.RestaurantId == currentrestaurant).ToList();
if (restaurantreview = 0)
{
    var none = "Sorry Your Restaurant Hasnt been Reviewd Yet";
}
else
{
    var averagefood = objCtx.Reviews
                            .Where(r => r.RestaurantId == currentrestaurant)
                            .Average(r => r.Food);
}
```

Comment: May be you want == instead of =. Also comparison is wrong. You may want to check against Count()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are comparing a list (returned by `ToList()`) to the integer `0`. *Actually you're not comparing - you have a single equals, so you're trying to assign `0` to a `List<T>` variable. I imagine this is a typo though.*

Perhaps you meant to check if there aren't `Any` reviews:

```
if (!restaurantreview.Any())
{
    //...
}
```

The other way to do this - and use your 0 - is to check the `Count` of items in the list:

```
if (restaurantreview.Count == 0)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: @Serv Yeah bad copy and paste from the OP. Already caught and fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

A List has 0 to n items, so what you are probably looking for is:

```
if (restaurantreview.Count == 0)
{
    var none = "Sorry Your Restaurant Hasnt been Reviewd Yet";
}
```

Please note, that `=` is used to assign values, not for checking equality. Use `==`.